# Struts : Generating HTML instead of a simple message?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

In my ApplicationResource.properties file, I can things like "welcome.message="Welcome""

and I would generate that in my jsp page with...

```
<h3><bean:message key="welcome.message"/></h3>
```

But say for example, I have a lot of html to generate, such as a list and list items for that secion...

How would I do that?

Comment: You want to dynamically generate HTML elements? Or read then from the property files?

Comment: Id like to do both of these... But for nor now, the property file solution will be fine as I am creating the non dynamic content for now...

Comment: Burn this. Start over. Dump Struts 1. JSP 2.x has this in its standard tag lib (fmt:message). Move on to Struts 2 if you must, Struts 1 offers no value whatsoever today.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to stop you from giving the entire HTML code in the property file. For example if you want the text to appear bold you can do `<B>Bold Text</B>` So for your select box you can put the entire set of HTML  tags in a property and set it where you want to set it.

As for dynamic content you can get a list of your objects in the action class and then use the **struts UI tags** to create the list or whatever you want.

Comment: Doesn't the ApplicationRecources.properties file only allow one line per element?

Comment: Yes but that line can be as long as you want it to be,